# How to configure network and the Internet to work with Linux Mint VM?

Tags: linux-mint

Today, I installed **Linux Mint 13** to try some applications, programs and other good things.
after installing it I don't have network connection.

I tried with all type of network switches and activated Legacy Network Adapter but it didn't work

When I turn it Linux Mint says : Disconnected - you are now offline.

- How to configure network and the Internet to work with Linux Mint VM ?

Thanks in advance and please answer soon.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your actual computer is connected to the intenet and in the VM settings set the Network Adapter to Bridged.